# Istio Ingress Gateway to serve Strimzi Apache Kafka on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, istio, strimzi

I have a question on how to configure the Strimzi Kafka Operator with an Istio Ingress Gateway to serve both the bootstrap and the broker services.

I have deployed Istio to with following Gateway and Virtual Services to server both the bootstrap and brokers:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: strimzi-kafka-gw-broker
  namespace: strimzi
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - myserver
    port:
      name: https
      number: 9094
      protocol: HTTP2
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: myserver-tls
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: strimzi-kafka-gw-bootstrap
  namespace: strimzi
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - myserver
    port:
      name: tls-9093
      number: 9093
      protocol: TLS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: myserver-tls
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: strimzi-kafka-vs-broker
  namespace: strimzi
spec:
  gateways:
  - strimzi-kafka-gw-broker
  hosts:
  - my-server
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kafka-cluster-01-kafka-brokers
        port:
          number: 9092
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: strimzi-kafka-vs-bootstrap
  namespace: strimzi
spec:
  gateways:
  - strimzi-kafka-gw-bootstrap
  hosts:
  - my-server
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 9093
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kafka-cluster-01-kafka-bootstrap
        port:
          number: 9092
```

The problem is, when I deploy the Kafka resource via Strimzi Kafka operator in Kubernetes, I need to set the advertised address and advertised port for the brokers to the kafka clients to be used via Ingress, it will also create a listener on the same port for Istio not being able to serve the same port.

Stimzi Kafka Resource:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: kafka-cluster-01
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.1.0
    replicas: 2
    listeners:
      - name: internal
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
        configuration:
          brokers:
          - broker: 0
            advertisedHost: my-server
            advertisedPort: 9094
          - broker: 1
            advertisedHost: my-server
            advertisedPort: 9094
          - broker: 2
            advertisedHost: my-server
            advertisedPort: 9094
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 2
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 2
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 2
      min.insync.replicas: 2
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.1"
      receive.message.max.bytes: 1513486160
      advertised: my-server
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 100Gi
        deleteClaim: false
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 100Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

How can I tell Kafka (Strimzi) to use use a advertised address and port for the brokers without creating a listener on it to use an Ingress (Istio) in front of it?

I didn't find this on the documentation of Strimzi.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the issue. Your Kafka CR configures a listener on port 9092 (the port in the broker pods). But it configures as the advertised addresses `my-server:9094` -> so you need to configure your Ingress to listen on 9094 and forward to the port 9092 on the pods. (the only possible issue is that you have the same advertisedHost for all brokers -> they will need to be different)

Comment: Yes, I want to forward the traffic from the ingress listener 9094 to the service with port 9092 (kubernetes internal). I thought the ingress will distribute access to port 9094 to all internal brokers, so that I only need the same advertised address for all brokers. But my problem actually is, when I connect to the bootstrap on port 9093, the Kafka client tries to connect to the brokers using their kubernetes internal address. Thats why I thought I need the advertised address, but they will create a listener on their own which results in the ingress not being able to bind on that port as well.

Comment: No, they don't create a listener on their own. The advertised* fields just override the configured advertised hostname in the broker. But from your comment I'm not sure if you understand how Kafka works. You cannot have a single ingress _distributing_ access. You need to provide direct access to each broker. That is why the advertised hostname needs to be always different. You need to have my-server-0:9094 for broker 0, my-server-1:9404 for broker 1 etc. And configure ingress for each of them.

Comment: `Gateway` is not a documented resource that can be used https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/configuring.html#assembly-accessing-kafka-outside-cluster-str More importantly, Kafka does not use an HTTP protocol

Comment: @Jakub ok I will try that out.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Gateway is an Istio resource.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, but does it support TCP protocol? Because `protocol: HTTP2` on port 9094 will not work since Kafka is not an HTTP/S service. Similarly, `http.match.uri` in your VirtualService doesn't make sense for Kafka, either, and you shouldn't need one service for both a broker and a bootstrap address

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, Istio does support alot of protocols. I changed the protocol to TCP in Istio. On the Gateway object, the listener is TLS. This seems to work with Kafka, but I might still have some traffic issues in Istio, because I can't connect to the brokers, even if I configure 3 different brokers in Istio and set their advertise adresses to them respectively. I will figure this out. Thanks so far.

Comment: You'll need to have the brokers setup to return the Istio address(es) back as `advertised.listeners`, which is the main problem. Looks like last year, Strimzi said [they wouldn't support Istio](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/issues/5255#issuecomment-874716706), but if you get it working, might be worth adding a PR

Comment: It seems to work now. I set
      `advertised.listeners: SSL://my-server:9093
      advertised: my-server
      listener.security.protocol.map: SSL:SSL
      inter.broker.listener.name: SSL`
and needed a DestinationRule on my Istio to route to the plaintext kubernetes services on port 9092.
But the messages are somewhat delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also circumvent the slowliness now. The problem was, that I used the kubernetes service `kafka-cluster-01-kafka-brokers` that the Strimzi Operator deployed, but it worked like a loadbalancer between my two kafka brokers, so it sometimes requested the wrong partition in my topic which the requested broker did not hold. After installing a dedicated service per broker pod, I was able to fully get a working kafka queue with Istio in front.

I just need to tell the Stimzi operator somehow, how to deploy a dedicated services per pod and label the pods respectively.

Comment: It seems not possible to tell the Strimzi operator to deploy a dedicated service per pod and label it respectively.
With listener type ingress, I can only create nginx ingress resources, not Istio.
But with the loadbalancer I got it working without Istio.